# Xcode - Show "scene dock" - it is hidden

Tags: xcode, dock

at first, I'm not even sure how this thing is really called. On some websites it seems to be called "dock" or "scene dock", well this black bar below an view while editing the GUI in Xcode. [Example Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/RM_YourFirstApp_iOS/Art/storyboard_vc_selected.jpg)

My problem is, that this bar appears in every tutorial and is used for different tasks (e.g. gestures), but in my Xcode-environment (4.3.2) it does not appear.

I looked all through the View-menu, I looked at the preferences, .... I just could not find any possibility, to show this "scene dock". Any Idea what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The "scene dock" is only visible in a Storyboard, not in a single xib file. Do you have a storyboard?
2. If its hidden in your storyboard somehow, don't worry. You don't need it actually. The "scene dock" shows nothing else than the contents of the Document Outline (The left panel in your xib or storyboard where the First responder can be found). You can add, edit or connect all elements in the Document Outline.